# Latex in Turkish

Tags: languages, turkish

I wish to create an article in Turkish in Latex. I want chapters, table of contents etc to appear in Turkish. For example when I write this,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Giriş}

\end{document}
```

I want the output as

```
 Bölüm 1 (that is Turkish for Chapter 1)

  Giriş (Turkish for Introduction)
```

Is that possible or just a dream?

Comment: You would be better off by switching to LuaTeX and using a unicode encoded document via `fontspec` package. If default fonts don't have the necessary characters, you can use your own system fonts for say capital i etc.

Answer (score 15):

As well as changing fixed strings like `chapter` into the specified language, `babel`  will enable the correct hyphenation patterns for the language.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Giriş}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg well they are not missing from this MWE, keep things simple initially, OK I'll add (makes my comment about hypehation more true:-)

Comment: Thanks David. It works but the letter "ş" is missing. I edited your comment to add the pic of the output. It does not recognize the other Turkish letters either, e.g ö, ğ etc. What can be done now?

Comment: @Günal I specified UTF8 input encoding (after egreg prompted me:-) the letters should work if your files are in that encoding. Make sure that your file is saved as utf-8