# Turkish S's unicode packages

Tags: symbols, unicode, languages

I am following this answer [Latex in Turkish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/latex-in-turkish) but I cannot seem to get my Turkish S's to appear.

I have tried copying and pasting the letters/symbols as well as using \char"

Any advice?

Comment: You probably need to provide more information about what you tried, what latex system you are using.  I have no issue with Davids example in that answer.

Comment: characters will not simply not appear, they will appear or you should have a warning in the log as to why they are not appearing. Please show the log file you get from the linked answer.

Comment: `\char` will not work if you are using pdftex (which is the intention for the code in that answer), what number did you give to `\char`, what error did you get?

Comment: Is a "Turkish S" equivalent to an S with a cedilla accent?